# Application Insights Security via AccessToken?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-security

Can I secure Application Insights write via an access token (similar to `SqlConnection.AccessToken`) or is InstrumentationKey the only method? If an access token is possible, does the C# `TelemetryClient` support it?

Answer (score 0):

Instrumentation key is the only option. You might be concerned about security; Microsoft acknowledges this concern but doesn't feel it's a major risk. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-faq#my-ikey-is-visible-in-my-web-page-source) Google Analytics uses the same approach if it makes a difference.